# Все кнопки съехали на телефоне после того как забилдил

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всех приветствую, сделал игру - забилдил и после того как я захожу в игру, все отлично, но ui элементы съехали. в unity все хорошо. как решить эту проблему? при билде надо указывать какие то настройки или что то другое?

я думал то что ничего не произойдет, и все будет хорошо. но кнопки съехали

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите как должно быть

Comment: у вас в юнити такой же размер экрана?